# batch script for deleting all but the newest folder and ignoring one specific folder

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "workdir=C:\orbis32\"
set "folder="
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir %workdir% /AD /B /TW /O-D') do (
    set "folder=%%~fi"
    goto :break
)
:break
echo newest... %folder%

for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir %workdir% /AD /B /TW /O-D') do   (
    echo rd /s /q "%%~fi"
)

pause
```

now i need to exclude one specific Folder (orbis32\logs) from this but im currently stuck

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Fine. And what is your specific question that complies with the rules of this site? Read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! This is not a place for requesting code for free!

Answer (score 0):

No need to first find the newest folder (by the way: it could be the `logs` folder) - `skip` is sufficient. Just filter out the `obis32\logs` lines from the `dir` command:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "workdir=C:\orbis32\"
set "folder="
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('dir %workdir% /AD /B /TW /O-D ^|find /i /v "orbis32\logs"') do (
    echo rd /s /q "%%~fi"
)
pause
```